# Running Network Associates PGP Command line from SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption, ssis, pgp

I'm using [Network Associates PGP](http://www.openpgp.org/members/nai.shtml) 6.5.8 Command line utility to decrypt an incoming file for import in an SSIS job. This is party of a very old legacy system so I can't change the decryption methodology.

*Manual passphrase :*

If I create a new [Execute Process Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms141166.aspx) in SSIS and pass the below command line arguments then PGP asks for a passpharse to unlock the secret key. Manually providing the passphrase allows PGP to successfully decrypt the file.

```
-o L:\xxxx\xxxxx\MyFile_decrypted.xml L:\xxxx\xxxxx\MyFile_Encrypted.xml +pubring=L:\pgp\keyring\pubring.pkr +secring=L:\pgp\keyring\secring.skr +force
```

[image]

*Automated Passphrase :*

Looking at the documentation, as below, I need to provide the passkey using the --passphrase argument

[image]

[image]

*Changing the arguments to add the passphrase*

```
-o L:\xxxx\xxxxx\MyFile_decrypted.xml L:\xxxx\xxxxx\MyFile_Encrypted.xml +pubring=L:\pgp\keyring\pubring.pkr +secring=L:\pgp\keyring\secring.skr +force --passphrase abcdef
```

The problem I have is that I need to provide the key as part of the command line arguments and so far this is not working. If I run through SSIS I get a process error, `the process exit code was "5" while the expected was "0".` Running directly via the command line provides a similar failure.

What is the correct syntax for providing the passphrase argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had a newer version of the documentation.

The documentation for [6.5.x](ftp://ftp.pgpi.org/pub/pgp/6.5/docs/english/PGPCmdLineGuide.pdf) passes the passphrase using the -z argument.

```
-z Identifies the passphrase on the command line. ( From Page 13 )
```

Changing my arguments as below resolved the issue.

```
-o L:\xxxx\xxxxx\MyFile_decrypted.xml L:\xxxx\xxxxx\MyFile_Encrypted.xml +pubring=L:\pgp\keyring\pubring.pkr +secring=L:\pgp\keyring\secring.skr +force -z abcdef
```